# How can I enable/disable the VS Code Sandbox?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to enable/disable VS Code sandbox mode to see how it works. But I could not find any specific documentation on how to enable it in current VS Code. How to enable/disable sandbox in VS Code? How sandbox actually works? Is it already enabled by default, if so, how can I disable it?

I tried installing VS Code Insiders also but could not locate "window.experimental.useSandbox" on the settings. I tried to add this into settings.json but it says the setting is not recognisable.

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/11/28/vscode-sandbox

Comment: Yes. I looked into this and got to know that we can enable sandboxing in vscode but could not find how to do it.

Comment: The blog post implies that they made it the default for everyone in early 2023, so there's no setting to change because it's already enabled.

Comment: Does that mean the ability to disable it is not possible?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for wanting to disable it?

Comment: Just wanted to check whether the sandboxing is working or not in vscode.

Comment: VSCode's sandboxing is an internal implementation detail that should have no effect on its users - so that's why I'm wanting to know why you're asking about this...

Comment: I thought the sandboxing feature is not given to the users yet as the setting itself refers to "experimental" and we have to enable. So if it is enabled by a setting, thought it can be disabled also. But if this is an internal implementation and its already there in the latest vscode versions, I think my question is not an actual question anymore :).

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox is enabled by default since early 2023. See https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/11/28/vscode-sandbox#_putting-it-all-together.

Related for running with no sandbox (TL;DR `code --no-sandbox`): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_unable-to-run-as-admin-when-applocker-is-enabled.

`window.experimental.useSandbox` is no longer in the latest Insiders as mentioned in the Sandbox blogpost since the feature is no longer experimental and has been made the default.